# How to pass the value dropdownlist without using form

Tags: javascript, php

I have two sets of option value. I created another dropdown that if I choose r it echo `<option value $row['nego'] >` or n echo `<option value $row['rfq'] >`. What I want is to pass the value of dropdown without using form. If it possible to do that?

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str == "") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('rfq_list.php?q=' + str) // or rfq_list.php?q
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>

    <select>
      <option value="r">rfq</option>
      <option value="n">nego</option>
    </select>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['n'])) {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT nego FROM purchase_order GROUP BY shop ORDER BY nego");
  $option = '';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['nego'].'">'.$row['nego'].'</option>';
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['r'])) {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT rfq FROM purchase_order WHERE rfq LIKE '13-___' OR rfq LIKE '1_-___' OR rfq LIKE '2_-___' GROUP BY rfq ORDER BY rfq");
  $option = '';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['rfq'].'">'.$row['rfq'].'</option>';
  }
}
?>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;">
  <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
  <?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

Comment: So you want to have an action occur every time the user changes the option selected? Why not have another `onchange` method?

Comment: Can you describe what the code you currently have does / doesn't do?

Comment: Another function, probably.

Comment: I still don't know exactly what it is that you want to do - you have not really tried to describe it so someone other than yourself can answer this. And tell me this - what is wrong with using "another form"? It's a nice convenient container for "an area of input".

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your code currently doesn't work at all? You are doing things like `isset($_POST['n'])` but your function `showUser` is making a `GET` request with a parameter `q`. I think you need to clean that up first - if you can either pass `q=n` or `q=r` or `q=ALL`, then you can test for the existence of the parameter and switch the code based on the value (`r`, `n`, or `ALL`). Think you can do that?

Comment: If I choose r in dropdownlist the <select name="users"> echo $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['rfq'].'">'.$row['rfq'].'</option>'; . Just pass the select value to $_POST it.